# Why java JDK gives option for all OS?

Tags: java

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u3-download-1501626.html

We know that java is a **Platform Independent Language** then why does this site provide JDKs for all OSes like Linux, Windows, Solaris?

Then why do we tell java is **Platform Independent**?

Comment: Because JVM isn't platform independent!

Comment: Because JVM isn't implemented in JAVA, but probably mostly C/C++

Comment: Why all the downvotes? this is really the most ridiculous forum I've seen. Someone is just asking a question, and they do not know. Why put everyone down for just asking a question if the question is very basic?

Comment: I dont know why DownVotes ? Its Really nice Question....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is like this:

```
      your application          
    ---------------------       
          JAVA on OS1           
    ---------------------
           OS1
    ---------------------
         hardware
    ---------------------
```

if you write your application on top of Java, then you can just move your java
application, as is, without changing it, or even compile it, to new OS, because
your program is written on one platform, which is Java, not the native OS.

So, you need to download specific Java for your OS. But from application point of view, it is the same API. Java makes your application platform independent since it hides the OS from your application. But Java itself, it has to be compiled and build for each specific OS. But the application do not care about that. The application sees the same API. That is the whole point.

Answer (score 4):

Because there you download the Installer for the Java Virtual Machine. This is the environment where your Java Application is running in.

The reason why Java is OS independent, is because its running in this JVM.

Comment: "vor", "Maschine", "Applikation"... [sic]...  Is the language you're using "Germanglish" or what!?   ; )

Comment: I prefer to call it "Denglish" :). Anyway I'm sorry about these typos.

Comment: don't worry: I'm a native french speaker and I make some good "frenglish" typos once in a while too ; )

Answer (score 2):

The JVM's job is to hide the differences between platforms and to provide the same execution environment to application code regardless of platform.

The JVM is written in C++, and is compiled to a native binary, just like any other C++ application. (You wouldn't expect a .exe file to run on Linux, after all).

So the JVM is platform-specific, but the environment it provides is not.

Answer (score 1):

To explain you in simple terms, you no need to compile your java source code when you move your code from one OS to another, but to run your compiled java code you need to have OS specific Java run time machine. Thats why you have different JDK for different OS.

Answer (score 1):

To add to others answers, Java is qualified Platform independent because the code you write is supposed to works on every platform. That's not totally true in fact. The Java code is always compiled in bytecode in the same way, but the JVM interprets this common bytecode in different way in function of the OS, there is one JVM per OS. OS that don't have a JVM implementation to use bytecode can't support Java.